# Exception thrown from bean: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/auth0/jwt/algorithms/Algorithm

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jwt

I'm trying to generate an jwt token and signing it with an Algorithm provided by the JWT library. When calling out the rest service login, I get this error when the method is trying to create the token.

```
javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Exception thrown from bean: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/auth0/jwt/algorithms/Algorithm
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.checkExceptionClientTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:668)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:509)
```

my imports

```
import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
```

The creation of the token method

```
try {
         Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC512("secret");       
         token
      =JWT.create().withSubject(username).withIssuer("OAuth").sign(algorithm);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
```

The jwt jar is included in the library
http://prntscr.com/nb4447

I can't figure out how this error is showing up because the Jwt library was provided by importing at as a dependency in maven.

Anyone got any solutions?

Comment: could you show us your pom?

Comment: Did you find out what was the issue ?

Comment: any update on this?